# Anchor a view to top of the screen when softkeyboard appears

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Looks like a simple problem, but I cannot find any solution.

My layout hierarchy is also simple:

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ...>
    />
    <RecyclerView
        ...>
    />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ...>
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What happens:
I have an `EditText`, which is a child of the footer layout. When it gains focus, the softkeyboard appears and the whole layout is pulled up.

What I want to achieve:
..., the softkeyboard appears and the header will **remain at the top**, the footer will be pulled above the softkeyboard (just like now), and the only resized view will be the `RecyclerView`.

I tried dozens of combinations with `windowSoftInputMode`, combining my layout with `ScrollView`... but nothing helps.

It must be easy, isnt it?

Edit: the layout is content view of DialogFragment

Answer (score 0):

Could you add your whole code, so I can test that and that will help us to find out and exact issue. Although I tried something which is working fine. Check my answer below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#00ff00" />

<RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/view_header"
    android:layout_above="@+id/view_footer"
    android:background="#006655"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#009911" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```